# .NET e-commerce/CMS UI-only options

Tags: .net, content-management-system, e-commerce

I have an e-commerce "platform" thats made up of various components.  From a business POV we run a single warehouse/distribution that has multiple sites targeting specific industries.  Each site is its own business unit and has silo'd data.

A quick explanation of what each component is would be;

- Logistics: A WCF project that contains all the logic and data storage for our warehouse to accept new shipments, print customer orders, dispatch them out the door, etc.
- Site Application: A WCF project that contains all the logic and data storage specifically for that sites audience.  It receives a product feed from the Logistics component about what it's allowed to sell (and price, etc).  Customers view those products, submit an order and the order is sent to the Logistics layer to be dispatched.
- Admin App: An MVC project that communicates with both projects based on user permissions to manipulate the data across each system (customers, orders, products, etc).
- Web UI App: This needs to communicate with the site app system to retrieve customer, product, order, etc data.

Now where I need some suggestions is how to implement the web UI.  I want it to run on a CMS-framework so that our marketing guys can manipulate the pages themselves without needing IT help, etc.

After looking at Orchard, Umbraco, Sitefinity, Kentico and Sitecore I'm wondering if what we need is more of an e-commerece frontend like nopCommerce or Virtocommerce.  However both of these are the full package which include inventory management, customer management, order management, etc which in our situation is controlled within the site app component.

If I could sum up the requirements of the web UI it would be that it needs to support a templating system for layout, page/blog management and plugin support to communicate with our app.

My question is; Is there a solution available that matches my requirements or should I pick a CMS like Umbraco that we can customise heavily to support that need?

Thanks!

Comment: It should be easy to plug your components (inventory, customer manager) to virtocommerce through prism.

Comment: [Virto Commerce](http://virtocommerce.com) has a module design, components that are not needed can be removed or replaced with a new ones that meet business requirements better. We did that for rutaobao.com where fulfillment/warehouse module has been custom build and integrated into the administration console. It has also been design to allow any CMS integration, since things like display templates are not hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

Sitefinity has module/widget design that is natural to any ASP.NET developer. Their ecommerce module also facilitates custom providers for products, types, etc so you can integrate your custom solution seamlessly into the CMS using the default widgets or easily develop your own.